# Beal's conjecture: confused about Wikipedia's page

Tags: number-theory, conjectures

[Beal's conjecture states](http://www.math.unt.edu/%7Emauldin/beal.html):
If $A^x + B^y = C^z$ for $A, B, C, x, y ,z$ are positive integers and $x,y,z>2$ then $A$ , $B$ and $C$ have a common prime factor.

As I understand, if for example $x$ is even, we can write $A^x=(A^{x/2})^2$ and $A^{x/2}$ is integer. We can do similar for factors of $x$ and keep one prime as the exponent. A similar approach is usually used when Fermat's Last Theorem is discussed.

**Question**: is it so that the conjecture allows only odd exponents? and is not it enough to prove the conjecture for only odd prime exponents (again similar to FLT discussions)?

If the answer to this question is yes, then why [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture#Partial_results) of Beal's conjecture presents special cases where one of the exponents is $2$ or another even number? For example why case $(x, y, z) = (3, 6, n)$ is permitted in Beal's conjecture?

Similar cases have been presented in many websites, such as [here](https://norvig.com/beal.html) where example $27^4 + 162^3 = 9^7$ is presented. It has been mentioned that this is not a counterexample because the base numbers share a factor, but isn't it that this is not even permitted in the conjecture?

Moreover, is there any example that fits in the equation of Beal's conjecture, the exponents are larger than 3 and the base numbers share a factor?

Comment: Edited. Thanks @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Note: you can’t replace $A^x$ with $(A^{x/2})^2$, because the conjecture requires the exponent to be *greater* than $2$. Instead, you want to replace it with $(A^2)^{x/2}$, but only if $x\gt 4$.

Comment: The conjecture is stated in many places, and none of them that I have seen require odd exponents.

Comment: Don’t confuse what is sufficient to establish the conjecture with what is “permitted” by the conjecture. The conjecture is stated for all exponents satisfying the given condition. Just because the general case would follow from a more restricted one does not mean the more general case is “not even permitted”. It just means you don’t have to consider it *if you can prove the specific case*. This was also true in FLT: FLT was proven for exponent $14$ by Dirichlet, before the proof for $n=7$ was established.

Comment: I mean if $A^x$ fits in the equation, $(A^{x/2})^2$ still fits in the equation but is not permitted in the conjecture. So why do we need to study cases that can be converted into a form that are not permitted at all?

Comment: An example with all exponents larger than $3$ is $2^4 + 2^4 = 2^5$.

Comment: @YetiYota: Yes, you are confused. The conjecture does not forbid anything. It makes *no assertion* about what happens when the exponents do not satisfy the given conditions. You say: “Well, I can turn an equation that satisfies the hypotheses into one that doesn’t.” to which the answer is “So what?”  You could turn a solution to the FLT equation for $n=4$ into one for $n=2$, but FLT is not about exponent $n=2$. Why do we do the $n=4$ case, then? Because FLT says *nothing* about the $n=2$ case. Same here.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Then what is the sufficient condition; exponents be prime, including 2? And if this is proved, then no need to study cases such as exponents are 4, 16, 180 and such. Am I correct?

Comment: I haven't read this question in detail, but it's not apparent to me why it was down-voted; it seems that OP made a good faith effort though perhaps a mistake

Comment: If you could prove it for any combination of exponents that are odd primes and 4 (**not** 2; that one is irrelevant!), then all cases would follow: because any $x\gt 2$  is either divisible by $4$ or by an odd prime, and same for $y$ and $z$. Just like with FLT.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you have been very helpful. Thanks man!